# How does a computer processes each and every command given to it?

Tags: process, operating-system, command, software-design

If I type in some command let be as simple as possible like print numbers from one to ten in BlueJ. Now since I have given a main command the computer processes the command and gives the output, but my question is how each and every number is printed by the computer is there any particular code integrated within the software of the computer which processes and prints each and every number each and every time the above code is ran?

Comment: Several books are needed to answer your too broad question. Install a Linux distribution on your computer, then read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [*Operating Systems / Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends upon the operating system. Here are two approaches:

I. In eunuchs variants the command interpreter is just a program. There is nothing special about it except that it processes commands. For the most part, commands simply map to programs. If you type "xyx" the command interpreter searches for an executable (or script) named xyz to execute. An environmental variable "PATH" defines the directories to search for the file.

II. In the VMS system, the command interpreter resides in a protected area of the process address space. For an interactive process, the command interpreter sits in the background while a program is running. Commands are defined by a table. If you type XYZ, the command interpreter looks for the XYZ command, figures out what the options to that command are, and runs the appropriate program. The actual program could be ABC and it is even possible that the same command could invoke different programs, depending upon the options supplied.